# psychopy ratingScale with numeric keypad

Tags: python, psychopy

In my task, I've been allowing responses using the numeric keypad (e.g 'num_1') as well as the regular numbers at the top of the keyboard (e.g. '1'). When I later ask for ratings using `ratingScale`, I'd like both options to be available as well, but I don't know how to achieve this.

As is, `ratingScale` does not accept responses with the numeric keypad. I can change this with `respKeys`, but I would have to provide "A list of keys to use for selecting choices, in the desired order". This means I can't allow both '1' and 'num_1' to select the first rating (e.g. with `respKeys = ['1','num_1, '2', 'num_2', ...]` '1' would select the first rating, 'num_1' the second, etc.).

Am I really stuck with either `respKeys = ['1','2','3','4','5']` or `respKeys = ['num_1','num_2','num_3','num_4','num_5']`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's any built-in ways for `visual.RatingScale` to take multiple keyboard keys for the same scale location.

If you're using coder, a hack could be to use `event.getKeys()` and `visual.RatingScale.setMarkerPos()`. So for a simple case with a rating scale with three positions:

```py
# Initiate psychopy stuff
from psychopy import visual, event
win = visual.Window()
scale = visual.RatingScale(win, low=1, high=3)

# A list of lists, each sublist being the keys which represents this location
keysLocation = [['1', 'num_1'], ['2', 'num_2'], ['3', 'num_3']]
respKeys = [key for keysLoc in keysLocation for key in keysLoc]  # looks complicated but it simply flattens the list to be non-nested

    # Present the ratingscale and wait for a response
    currentPos = 1
    while scale.noResponse:
        response = event.getKeys(keyList=respKeys)  # only accept respKeys
        if response and response[0] in respKeys:
            # Then loop through sublists and update currentPos to where the match is
            for i, loc in enumerate(keysLocation):
                if response[0] in loc:
                    currentPos = i

        # Set the marker position and draw
        scale.setMarkerPos(currentPos)
        scale.draw()
        win.flip()
```

My solution looks complicated but most of it is just about handling the `keysLocation`list and searching it for matches. Sorry for the bad/ambiguous variable names but I couldn't come up with anything better right now.

This solution could probably also work in Builder. Just remove the "initiate psychopy" stuff, change `scale` to the name of your RatingScale, and paste the code into a code component just above the RatingScale.